# I would like to embed ffmpeg in my app for the Mac App Store. Is this compliant with the license ? is there any other blocker to achieve my goal?

Tags: licensing, apple-app-store

I am developing an application for macOS on the Mac App Store, and I would like to embed ffmpeg into the application's binary. Is this compliant with the ffmpeg license and does anybody have experience of doing this on the Mac App Store ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic linking LGPL library and licensing in Windows Store app](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/dynamic-linking-lgpl-library-and-licensing-in-windows-store-app) - while this is nominally for the Windows Store, the same points apply to Apple's variant.